# How to sync the time to network with timedatectl on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, systemd, time

I've installed the OS and the time is incorrect.

The `timedatectl` shows:

```
       System clock synchronized: no
systemd-timesyncd.service active: yes
                 RTC in local TZ: no
```

How to force it to sync now?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

From [`man timedatectl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/timedatectl.1.html) all you need is to enable NTP-sync.

```
sudo timedatectl set-ntp true
```

then it do the rest automatically.

If it does not work check status of `systemd-timesyncd.service`

```
systemctl status systemd-timesyncd.service
```

and restart it

```
sudo systemctl restart systemd-timesyncd.service
```

And then check again:

```
$ timedatectl
...
       System clock synchronized: yes
systemd-timesyncd.service active: yes
                 RTC in local TZ: no
```

Comment: The status of `systemd-timesyncd.service` was useful - helped to see the problem with the server connectivity.

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04 this doesn't work... can someone please verify?

Comment: @lewis4u: it works for me in Ubuntu18.04, the `systemctl` part. Does your firewall allow you to access the NTP servers?

Comment: @lewis4u: are time servers configured? can you check `/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf` ? You can see what time servers are used using the above systemctl status command. Indeed, on my 18.04 synchronization was off and setting set-ntp to on did not work until I set time servers.

Comment: Inside time servers everything is commented out... only `[Time]` is not

Comment: Even after restarting `systemd-timesynd.service`, `timedatectl` still reports `System clock synchronized: no`. Does anyone know why this would be?

Comment: @snark: There is a missing step here. You must have ntp installed, which it is not by default. `sudo apt install ntp`, then reboot.

Comment: @PresidentJamesMoveonPolk: At least on Ubuntu 20.04, `ntp` conflicts with `systemd-timesyncd` and wants to remove it. It must be something else. In my case, the error was a typo in the NTP configuration.

Comment: What should I do for it to start automatically start in reboot?

Comment: systemctl status systemd-timesyncd.service
Unit systemd-timesyncd.service could not be found.

Comment: Failed to restart systemd-timesyncd.service: Unit systemd-timesyncd.service is masked. It does not work

Comment: @maiky If and when a service is masked, you can always unmask it. Like, `sudo systemctl unmask systemd-timesyncd`

Comment: @maiky However, it won't automatically start when you boot the system unless it's enabled: `sudo systemctl enable systemd-timesyncd` and of course, to prevent it from automatically starting while leaving you the option to manually start and call the service, you can disable it but leave it unmasked: `sudo systemctl disable systemd-timesyncd`

Answer (score 5):

It worked for me, when I edited `/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf`, because lines below were commented.
I uncommented them and changed NTP and FallbackNTP lines by my Network servers:

```
[Time]
NTP=172.24.3.1
FallbackNTP=172.24.44.51
RootDistanceMaxSec=5
PollIntervalMinSec=32
PollIntervalMaxSec=2048
```

After that, I restarted `systemd-timesyncd.service`, so `System clock synchronized` status turned to `yes`

Comment: I don't have this file centos